# Survey JS Radio Calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, surveyjs

Using [Survey JS](https://surveyjs.io/Overview/Library/), the idea is to ask users to answer a number of questions from a pre-defined list of options (radio buttons).

Each option will be allocated a score (0, 25, 75, 100), as each selection is made i'd like to display the live score somewhere on screen.

I know I need to create an expression like in [this example](https://surveyjs.io/Examples/Library/?id=questiontype-expression), but i'm not sure where to start.

I've created the basic structure of the form, can be [seen here](https://jsfiddle.net/6yt5zq7s/2/).

```
$.material.init();

var json = {
  title: "Audit Example",
  showProgressBar: "top",
  pages: [{
    questions: [{
      type: "matrix",
      name: "Quality",
      title: "Please score each department below.",
      columns: [{
        value: 0,
        text: "None"
      }, {
        value: 25,
        text: "Isolated"
      }, {
        value: 50,
        text: "Some"
      }, {
        value: 100,
        text: "Widespread"
      }],
      rows: [{
        value: "training",
        text: "Training"
      }, {
        value: "support",
        text: "Support"
      }, {
        value: "safety",
        text: "Safety"
      }, {
        value: "communication",
        text: "Communication"
      }]
    }]
  }
  ]
};

Survey.defaultBootstrapMaterialCss.navigationButton = "btn btn-green";
Survey.defaultBootstrapMaterialCss.rating.item = "btn btn-default my-rating";
Survey.Survey.cssType = "bootstrapmaterial";

var survey = new Survey.Model(json);

survey.onComplete.add(function(result) {
  document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = "result: " + JSON.stringify(result.data);
});

survey.render("surveyElement");
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Could you please describe what you want to achieve? Is computing the sum of elements causing any trouble? Or you want it to work interactively like in example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let assume your question is to display sum of elements dynamically.

To do so, you can register your own function like:

```
function sumInObject(params) {
  if (params.length != 1) return 0;
  if(!params[0]) return 0;
  const object = params[0];
  const array = Object.keys(object)
    .map(key => object[key])
    .map(value => parseInt(value));
  return array.reduce((left, right) => left + right);
}

Survey.FunctionFactory.Instance.register("sumInObject", sumInObject);
```

And then use it like:

```
}, {
    "type": "expression",
    "name": "total",
    "title": "Total Quality:",
    "expression": "sumInObject({Quality})",
    "displayStyle": "decimal",
    "startWithNewLine": true
}
```

[Full code in Plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/GXPkeVaYrQAGYIONrjui)

Hope that it would help.